# Sockets: delay between receive and send (WriteStream.WriteAsync() and ReadStream.ReadAsync())

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.forms, exception

How do you Correctly implement a delay between sending a string using **WriteStream.WriteAsync()** and waiting for a response using **ReadStream.ReadAsync()**?

I am using the rda.SocketsForPCL plugin to create the TCP client socket and thereafter the respective read and write streams.

When I implement a delay using TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)), I get an System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in VS 2017. I am new to C# and Xamarin and I am not sure how to implement a delay other than the above method that will not cause an exception to be thrown.

Is there a "Global" exception handler that can be somehow implemented to deal with exceptions such as these as VS 2017 does not break the code and show you exactly where the exception has actually occurred?

I have implemented the below activity Page in Xamarin.Forms but it is not allowing me to implement a delay using the **TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));** which is commented in the UpdateUserDataAsync() function below:

```
 public InputPage ()
{
    try
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string err = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }

    client = SharedSocket.Instance().getSocket();                   // Get persistent Socket ===> client connection
    UpdateUserDataAsync();                                          // Used to update the contents of the Listview
    loadSampleData();                                               // Load the Items in the ListView   

    BindingContext = this;

    this.BindingContext = new Relays();                             // Binding the Listview items
    var neg = lstView.BindingContext as Relays;
    InputID = neg.ID;
}

private async void UpdateUserDataAsync()                        // Request and Receive Controller Name
{
    byte[] rv = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };    // Request
    Send_CntrP(rv);                                             // Send request
   //await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
rec2 = await ReceiveByte();
}// UpdateUserDataAsync

private void loadSampleData()
{
    ObservableCollection<Relays> lisInputs = new ObservableCollection<Relays>();

    if (rec2.Length >= 4)
    {
        byte[] states = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rec2);      // Create byte array of received string

        for (int j=6; j<22; j++)
        {
            switch (states[j])
            {
                case 0x00:                                         
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "ERROR" + (j - 5), State = "ERROR" });
                    break;

                case 0x01:                                         
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "IOK" + (j - 5), ImageUrl = "round_on.png", State= "Toggle"});
                     break;

                case 0x02:                                          
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "IOK" + (j - 5), ImageUrl = "round_on.png", State = "ON"});
                    break;

                case 0x03:                                          
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "IOK" + (j - 5), ImageUrl = "round_on.png", State = "OFF"});
                    break;

                case 0x04:                                          
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "IOK" + (j - 5), ImageUrl = "round_on.png", State = "NO"});
                    break;

                case 0x05:                                         
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "IOK" + (j - 5), ImageUrl = "round_on.png", State = "NC"});
                    break;

                case 0x10:                                          
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "IOK" + (j - 5), ImageUrl = "round_on.png", State = "SC"});
                    break;

                case 0x11:                                         
                  lisInputs.Add(new Relays { ID = j - 5, Name = "IOK" + (j - 5), ImageUrl = "round_on.png", State = "OC"});
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            Images[i] = "round_off.png";
            InputName[i] = "ERROR";
            InputOn[i] = false;
            InputState[i] = "ERROR";

            lisInputs.Add(new Relays { Name = InputName[i] + i, ImageUrl = Images[i], ID = i, State = InputState[i] });
        }
    }

    lstView.ItemsSource = lisInputs;
}

public class MyListItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Relays MyItem { get; set; }

    public MyListItemEventArgs(Relays item)
    {
        this.MyItem = item;
    }
}

// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++ Sending Messages+++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++++
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
public async void Send_CntrP(byte[] Comms)
{
    var Len = Comms.Length;                                        // Read the byte array Length

    if (client.Socket.Connected && Len <= 23)                       // No longer than 22 bytes of data to be sent                        
    {
        try
        {
            await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(Comms, 0, Len);    // Send data of specified Length
            await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();                           // Make sure all the buffer output data is sent   
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));      // Delay before next TX to ensure buffer is emptied correctly
        }
        catch (Exception ex)                                       // Exception Handler
        {
            return;
            throw ex;
        }
    }// Client Connected

    else
    {
        XFToast.ShortMessage("Error updating name.\n\rPlease check the connection or length of the entry");   //Android Native Toast Message
    }
}// Send_CntrP 
 // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Receiving Messages +++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
public async Task<string> ReceiveByte()           // Receive messages Asynchronously
{
    int bytesRec = 0;
    var buffer = new byte[28];

    if (client.Socket.Connected)                  // Check Socket connection
    {      
        while (bytesRec != -1)                    // Read received data ---> byte-by-byte
        {
            try
            {
                bytesRec = await client.ReadStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 28);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)                  // Exception Handler (to prevent App crash)
            {
                XFToast.ShortMessage("Error receiving message.\n\rPlease check the WIFI connection.");
                return "ERROR";                   // Return an "ERROR" message if failed
                throw ex;
            }

            var meh = buffer.ToArray();                              
            rec2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(meh);         

            if (rec2.Length >= 1 && rec2.Length < 30)                
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(rec2);                  // Return a string 
            }
            else
            {
                //await DisplayAlert("Error", "Error receiving message.", "OK");
                XFToast.ShortMessage("Error receiving message.\n\rPlease verify the connection.");   //Android Native Toast Message
                return "ERROR";         // Return an "ERROR" message
            }
        }// Reading response 
    }// Client
    else
    {
        return err;     // Return a "Connection Error" string when no connection is available
    }

    return rec2;         // Return the received bytes in a string 
}// ReceiveByte
// 
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 }
```

I am sorry for the long post but I have been struggling with this problem for a while now and I am not experienced enough to deal with all the async methods and exception "finding" and then the handling thereof with VS 2017 and Xamarin as I am still learning the basics :(

Thank you in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: I usually put the read and write code into the same lock so only one can occur at a time.  Then you never do both a read and write at the same time and you are always waiting for the write to complete before reading.

Comment: @jdweng, how would I put them in the same lock (or block) as you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code of my solution

```
    enum READ_WRITE
    {
        READ,
        WRITE
    }
    public class Test
    {
        private static readonly object readWritelock = new object();
        public static object ReadWrite(READ_WRITE readWrite, object data)
        {
            object returnValue = 0;
            lock (readWritelock)
            {
                switch (readWrite)
                {
                    case READ_WRITE.READ :
                        //add you read code here
                        break;

                    case READ_WRITE.WRITE :
                        //add your write code here
                        break;
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go try and implement this in my code.

Comment: I am still not able to implement a delay between sending and receiving; when I send and call the receive, it reads a bunch of zeros. Could this be because it is trying to read the received message too fast?

Comment: I don't know enough about xamarin to give an answer, but do know database architecture very well.  You basically have a database and the question is the database designed to handle shared transactions.  A shared database contains locking methods that make sure you do not have conflicts.  If you have a database with 10 items and one customer buys 9 items at the same time another customer want 5 items.  What does the 2nd customer get?A database that is designed for sharing the second customer get 1 item.  A database the is not designed for sharing gives the 2nd customer 5 items (4 do not exist).